# Using find, sqlite3, and xargs, to combine many small sqlite database files

Tags: sqlite, find, xargs

I have lots of small sqlite database files. Each was produced by a java application that ran.  I would like to combine them into a single database with find.

```
find . -name '*.db' -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} -P 4 `sqlite3 .dump {} | sqlite3 Combined.db`
```

OR

```
find . -name '*.db' -exec sqlite3 {} .dump \; | sqlite3 Combined.db
```

The most success I've had so far is when the contents of one database was written to Combined.db.  All other variations have resulted in errors.

Comment: You have to filter out the superfluous CREATE TABLE statements, or at least replace them with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.

Comment: I could probably pipe things through sed to replace CRATE TABLE with CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.  Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that in parallel:

```
Error: near line 14: database is locked
Error: near line 3: database is locked
```

But you *can* do:

```
mrg() {
  sqlite3 "$1" .dump |
    perl -pe 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g;' |
    sqlite3 cmb;
}
export -f mrg
find . -name '*.db' | parallel -j1 mrg
```